# How to create more space around paragraph text

Tags: html, css

Just wondering what the best way is to reduce how much the paragraph text spans in my section. As you can see from the code, the text takes up nearly the whole width. However, I would like it to take up less and have more lines than two. I have included an image of what I am looking for. [image: This is an example of what I am looking for.]

https://jsfiddle.net/cabtjsky/

```
<h1>WELCOME</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas dapibus est justo, sit amet sodales erat gravida nec. 
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris enim sapien, iaculis a auctor vitae, eleifend in augue. 
Mauris turpis ligula, tincidunt ut augue et, dictum consequat nisl.</p>
</section>

#section1{
height:auto;
width:100%;
background-color:green;
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
align-items:center;
text-align:center;
padding-top:100px;
padding-bottom:100px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just reduce the width of the paragraph, e.g. with `width: 60%;`.

But a better solution would be to add left and right padding, with a `box-sizing: border-box`. This includes the padding space into your `width: 100%`:

```css
#section1 {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section id="section1">
  <h1>WELCOME</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas dapibus est justo, sit amet sodales erat gravida nec. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris enim sapien, iaculis a auctor vitae, eleifend in augue. Mauris turpis ligula, tincidunt ut augue et, dictum consequat nisl.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that applying global styles like this can have lead to very messy CSS down the road. It's best to create sensible, reusable classes instead of blinding applying styles to whatever is there at the time.

Comment: It was just an example, but you are right. Working with reusable classe is the better way. Anyway, I added a solution with padding and border-box which is the better one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Andreas & thank you TW80000 for your input and help.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this, but I would wrap the paragraph in a div and apply a style to the div to reduce the width.

```css
#section1 {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.half-width {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section id="section1">
  <h1>WELCOME</h1>
  <div class="half-width">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas dapibus est justo, sit amet sodales erat gravida nec. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris enim sapien, iaculis a auctor vitae,
      eleifend in augue. Mauris turpis ligula, tincidunt ut augue et, dictum consequat nisl.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete width entirely and add:

```
padding-right:150px;
padding-left:150px;
```

This will "pad" the inside of the section box.

Comment: Or more simply: `padding: 0 150px;` (DRY)

Answer (score 1):

```css
#section1 {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section id="section1">
  <h1>WELCOME</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas dapibus est justo, sit amet sodales erat gravida nec. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris enim sapien, iaculis a auctor vitae, eleifend in augue. Mauris turpis ligula, tincidunt ut augue et, dictum consequat nisl.</p>
</section>
```